# How to know that my Chrome extensions's badge icon was Shift-clicked?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension and I need to know when its badge icon was shift-clicked:

[image]

PS. My extension shows a pop-up window upon a regular click on the badge:

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "images/icon19.png",
        "38": "images/icon38.png"
    },
        "default_title": "__MSG_main_title__",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you can't.

Slightly longer, there is an active feature request for that: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=61445

Comment: Thanks. Except that it's been a feature request for 4 yrs :) The only somewhat working workaround that I could come up with is to add `keydown` and `keyup` event listeners to the popup `window` and cache the `shift` key state in the global variable. The problem though is that one can use it only after a small delay (to let those key events propagate) which makes it very unreliable.